# Preventing elements to go behind fixed div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Consider the example below

HTML

```
<div class="top">
    Hello
    <div>
        <a href="content">Click Here</a>
        <div id="content">Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.top{
     position: fixed;
}  

#content{
     margin-top: 100px;
}
```

When the link Click here is clicked, the contents of class `content` goes behind `top` class, is there any way I can prevent this? Like the contents of id `content` should always be displayed after class `top` Can this be achieved using CSS or jQuery?

Comment: set `z-index` property in css

Comment: First fix this (<div class=""top>) to <div class="top">

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6L95omga/1/ - can you recreate the issue?

Answer (score 2):

It's the `z-index` css property. It only takes effect if element `position` is not static: `fixed`, `relative` or `absolute`:

```css
.top a {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
#content {
  border: 1px solid #898989;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  Hello
  <div>
    <a href="content">Click Here</a>
    <div id="content">
      Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What we are doing here is preventing elements to go on top of class `top` by adding z-index to that class. What I asked for is how to prevent elements to go behind that class? If you set opacity to 'top' class in your code, you will see that elements are still going behind that class.

Comment: @LuckyAli Your `.top` is parent of `#content` so there is no possibility for `.top` to be on top of `#content`. Please provide working SO Snippet or JSFiddle with issue than.

Comment: Ok, I will do a fiddle. Give me a moment here.